How to count votes in Cosmos SDK 0.5 to find if consensus is reached
I've searched through all available docs for Cosmos SDK.
With all docs, still can't find any information, how to calculate votes for a block, especially in the light of the recent updates from 0.48 to 0.5 where BeginBlock and EndBlock doesn't have request argument.
I need to calculate if consensus is reached.

If you're looking for consensus calculation, it's related to CometBFT rather than Cosmos-sdk. For this you have to understand voting power, prevote, precommit and commit. In short, if total voting power is 100, consensus is reached when validators of 2/3 voting power have precommitted to the same block! For visual example check the following link which shows the cosmos validators consensus state
